# apache - Is hosting same website on different ports possible?

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

Someone asked me to install an SSL certificate for a website. I installed it and enabled HTTPS but he got pissed that HTTP requests get redirected to HTTPS instead. I don't think redirection would work because it may cause a redirect loop. I did try it but it didn't work. I'm using virtual hosts, and one and only one server.

The question is: Is it possible to host the same, exact website on different ports? (i.e. the website is accessible on both http://www.website.com and https://www.website.com) (i.e. the virtual host is exactly the same, except that one is listening to port 80 and another one is listening on port 443)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirection from http to https indeed works with apache and `mod_rewrite`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

DocumentRoot /var/www
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^/(.*)         https://www.website.com/$1 [L,R]
[....]
</VirtualHost>
```

On the other hand, to answer to your question, it is possibile to serve the same exact site on differente vhost, if the `DocumentRoot` is the same.

Comment: Ooo. Okay cool.